# finding a string in pandas dataframe column and cell

Tags: python, pandas, search, text

I have a dataframe as below and I want to find how many times value from the column `Jan` occurs in the column `URL` and corresponding cell of the column `URL`.

I want to create 3 columns - `found in cell` and `found in column` and `distinct finds` 
For example when we search for value `try` from the first cell of the column `Jan`, it should return 1 in `found in cell` and 2 in 'found in column`and 2 in`distinct finds`because the word was found in 2 rows
when we search for value`why`from the second cell of the column`Jan`, it should return 0 in`found in cell`and 2 in 'found in column` and 2 in `distinct finds` because the word was found in 2 rows

i know how to search within a string. But how could i search within a cell and within a column?

```
s="ea2017-104.pdf bb cc for why"
s.lower().count("why")#to find text within string

sales = [{'account': '3', 'Jan': 'try', 'Feb': '200 .jones', 'URL': 'ea2018-001.pdf try bbbbb why try'},
             {'account': '1',  'Jan': 'why', 'Feb': '210', 'URL': 'try '},
             {'account': '2',  'Jan': 'bbbbb',  'Feb': '90',  'URL': 'ea2017-104.pdf bb cc for why' }]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
df

df['column_find']=df['URL'].str.lower().count('why')
```

final output
will have 3 additional columns as below

```
found_inCell    found_in_column           distinct_finds
2                3                   2
0                2                   2
0                1                   1
```

## update

I get an error when i try to run code  when one of the cells in empty/np.nan

```
sales = [{'account': '3', 'Jan': np.nan, 'Feb': '200 .jones', 'URL': 'ea2018-001.pdf try bbbbb why try'},
             {'account': '1',  'Jan': 'try', 'Feb': '210', 'URL': 'try '},
             {'account': '2',  'Jan': 'bbbbb',  'Feb': '90',  'URL': 'ea2017-104.pdf bb cc for why' }]
df = pd.DataFrame(sales)
df

df['found_inCell'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['URL'].count(row['Jan']), axis=1)
df['found_in_column'] = df['Jan'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(df['URL'].tolist()).count(x))
df['distinct_finds'] = df['Jan'].apply(lambda x: sum(df['URL'].str.contains(x)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way.

```
df['found_inCell'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['URL'].count(row['Jan']), axis=1)
df['found_in_column'] = df['Jan'].apply(lambda x: ''.join(df['URL'].tolist()).count(x))
df['distinct_finds'] = df['Jan'].apply(lambda x: sum(df['URL'].str.contains(x)))

#           Feb    Jan                           URL account  found_inCell  \
# 0  200 .jones    try  ea2018-001.pdf try bbbbb why       3             1   
# 1         210    why                          try        1             0   
# 2          90  bbbbb  ea2017-104.pdf bb cc for why       2             0   

#    found_in_column  distinct_finds  
# 0                2               2  
# 1                2               2  
# 2                1               1
```

Comment: thanks...it is working...let me do a bit more testing

Comment: i get an error `'must be str, not NoneType'` if a cell in column `Jan` is empty...how could i modify the apply function such that it just skips row when the value in the cell is empty?